# Zero KB available on NFS Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, permissions, operating-systems, nfs

I can't write to my NFS (Xtreamer media player).
Writing works fine via Terminal, but in Finder everything is read only and Finder says "Zero KB available." and gives me the error message "The item abc.rtf can't be copied because there isn't enough free space." when I try to copy files to the NFS.
Creating folders works fine, but copying files to them does not work.

Any ideas?

Johan

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but NFS uses UIDs to determine permissions. Are you sure you're using the same UID to log in with both the terminal and the GUI? You can see what your UID is (in 10.5 or 10.6 only) by going to System Preferences > Accounts pane and Control-Clicking on the account to get the Advanced Options.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I'm connecting using the same UID.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if you still care about this problem, but I’m posting the solution here to be found by others experiencing this problem.

First, you need to get the [Xtreamer Mod Pack](http://forum.xtreamer.net/mediawiki-1.15.1/index.php/Xtreamer_Mod_Pack)

This will allow you to enable telnet access to the xtreamer. After you start the telnet server, telnet to the xtreamer and edit the smb config file at: `/usr/local/daemon/samba/lib/smb.conf`

Change the `get quota command` parameter under the `[global]` section to `/usr/local/daemon/samba/sbin/my_get_quota`.

Then you need to change the path variable of the `[Xtreamer]` section to point to you hard drive, and not to `/tmp/usbmounts`. In my case, I had to change it to `/tmp/usbmounts/sda1`

The last thing to do is to create the `my_get_quota` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
print 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Now restart the smb server by running:

```
killall smbd
/usr/local/daemon/samba/sbin/smbd -D
```

That’s it. Finder should now report the correct size and allow you to copy files.